# How can I get PowerShell to figure out my "string X string-array" parameter sets?

Tags: powershell, parameters

I'm writing a path manipulator function, which takes two arguments, either of which can be a `String`, or an `Array` of strings:

```
function wranglePath(
    [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = "arr-arr")]
    [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = "arr-joined")]
    [String[]]$AugendArray,
    [Parameter(Position = 1, Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = "arr-arr")]
    [Parameter(Position = 1, Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = "joined-arr")]
    [String[]]$AddendArray,
    [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = "joined-joined")]    
    [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = "joined-arr")]
    [String]$AugendJoined,
    [Parameter(Position = 1, Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = "joined-joined")]
    [Parameter(Position = 1, Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = "arr-joined")]
    [String]$AddendJoined
) {
    switch ($PsCmdlet.ParameterSetName) {
        "arr-arr" { 
            Write-Host "arr-arr"
        }
        "arr-joined" {
            Write-Host "arr-joined"            
        }
        "joined-arr" { 
            Write-Host "joined-arr" 
        }
        "joined-joined" { 
            Write-Host "joined-joined"
        }
    }
}
```

I want PowerShell to determine the correct `ParameterSetName` by the types of arguments passed, I don't want to get `PSObject` and figure it out in the function.

If I call my function with named arguments, it behaves as desired. But when I pass two strings without naming the arguments, it fails with an `ambiguousparameterset` error.

The Function I am writing returns an `Array` of `String` representations of file paths where each element has been cleaned and verified. The two parameters are the `Augend` and the `Addend`, and each is either a single `String` comprised of path elements joined by the `Path Delimiter Character`, or an `Array` of strings. If an argument is an `Array`, no element is permitted to contain the `Path Delimiter Character`. If an argument is a single `String`, the function splits the String, and converts it into an `Array` of strings. This is a multi-platform function.

How can I get PowerShell to do this?

Comment: A parameter of an array type can always take a value of the base type of the array, and it will be coerced into an array of one entry - that is, you can always pass a single `int` to a parameter of type `int[]`, and your code will work. Because of this, the way you have your parameters defined will not be sufficiently disambiguated when you rely on the position rather than naming them.

Comment: So is the answer "You can't."? It pretty much seems that way.

Comment: Please take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution. What are you trying to accomplish with the different parameter sets and the arguments passed to them?

Comment: Given the specific parameter definitions that you've provided, no, you can't, because of the possible coercion of a "scalar" type to the corresponding array. In general, however, as long as each parameter set has at least one parameter in common with no other parameter set, or the combination of parameters by type is unique, PowerShell can identify which parameter set is intended. It is partially for this reason that I generally advise people writing PowerShell scripts _not_ to rely on positional parameters (always use named parameters).